# Returning large integer values in Cypher results in the number changing, why?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

According neo4j's developer manual:

> integer   64-bit integer -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807,
>   inclusive

But when I run cypher in neo4j browser:

```
return 9223372036854775807;
```

the result is:

```
╒═════════════════════╕
│"9223372036854775807"│
╞═════════════════════╡
│9223372036854776000  │
└─────────────────────┘
```

**the return value is changed to `9223372036854776000` !!!**

another example is:

```
return 1952334015959045784;
```

result is:

```
╒═════════════════════╕
│"1952334015959045784"│
╞═════════════════════╡
│1952334015959046000  │
└─────────────────────┘
```

the value is also changed !!! why ??

ps: The neo4j i used is Community Edition 3.2.3.

Comment: On the linked question that this duplicates, I updated my answer to indicate 3.2.3 is also affected by the bug. The bug is fixed in 3.2.5, so please upgrade to that version or later. The bug only affects display in the browser; the underlying queries and data returned using neo4j itself and the drivers is correct, so usage of cypher-shell and the drivers will yield correct data on all versions.